# Error when booting 12.10 after upgrade

Tags: boot, wubi, 12.10

Since upgrading to 12.10 from 12.04, I get the following error every time it boots:

```
 /scripts/init-premount/devpts: line 21 mountpoint not found
```

It does, however, skip over that and continue to boot.

I can't find that location, however. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what that exactly happens, but that `/scripts/init-premount/devpts` is probably inside the initramfs. To locate the real file, you can do `locate init-premount/devpts`. Posting the problematic line will help resolve the problem.

Note: I don't have that file here on my machine (12.04), but I do have the folders `/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-premount` and `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-premount`, but I will soon upgrade and look again.

Sorry, I can't comment, so I do it now via an answer.

Update: you can also try `sudo update-initramfs`. It might just fix it for you.

Comment: I tried your second thing, the sudo update one, with several different arguments including the one with the kernel version. None of those helped. 

I did find the file in that /usr location you mentioned. Line 21 reads:

mountpoint -q /dev/pts || exit 0

Comment: It seems to be related to `dropbear` (see http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/i386/dropbear/filelist). You can try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure dropbear` or, if you don't need dropbear, try uninstalling it via `sudo apt-get purge dropbear` (the purge is important as it removes the configuration too). Or at least to check whether dropbear causes it.

Comment: Update: it seems to be related to the mountpoint command. I have reported a bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sysvinit/+bug/1070992

Answer (score -1):

You made a bad upgrade . What I can advise you is to reinstall Ubuntu 12.04 And keep it or Install directly 12.10 without making the upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10. if you're not sure how to do it and know how to do it .